# How to find specific value from XML file and compare it with existing value and print on console as true or false

Tags: java, xml-parsing

I have the following xml with atleast 150 row numbers. How can i go into each rownumber and validate if specific value such as EX1 and DX1 is present  or not and if present i want to print it on console and return the value as true and if not return it as false. I am using Eclipse with JAVA.

```
<row rowNumber="0">
        <value columnNumber="0">TEST</value>
        <value columnNumber="1">303017</value>
        <value columnNumber="2">EX1</value>
        <value columnNumber="3">DX1</value>
        <value columnNumber="4">2014-09-08</value>
        <value columnNumber="5">3</value>
        <value columnNumber="6">45</value>
        <value columnNumber="7">2</value>
        <value columnNumber="8">2014-09-08</value>
        <value columnNumber="9">24</value>
    </row>
    -
    <row rowNumber="1">
        <value columnNumber="0">TEST</value>
        <value columnNumber="1">303017</value>
        <value columnNumber="2">EX1</value>
        <value columnNumber="3">DX2</value>
        <value columnNumber="4">2014-09-08 </value>
        <value columnNumber="5">0</value>
        <value columnNumber="6">45</value>
        <value columnNumber="7">2</value>
        <value columnNumber="8">2014-09-08</value>
        <value columnNumber="9">25</value>
    </row>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have write a small xml parser for this...

Just to start with -

```
public class MySAXParser {
    private static SAXParserFactory spf = null;
    private static SAXParser sp = null;
    private static MySAXHandler sh = null;

    public void parseXmlFile(int questionNo) {
        try {
            if(spf == null) {
                spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            }
            if(sp == null) {
                sp =  spf.newSAXParser() ;
            }
            if(sh == null) {
                sh =  new MySAXHandler();
            }
        sp.parse(new File("filePath.xml"), sh);

    } catch (SAXException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException io) {
         io.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
```

here, sh(MySAXHandler) should implement the default (DefaultHandler) handler which should help you read the xml specific to each row and compare the element values.

3am here..can't think of anything else...